# How can evalq source a file in correct environment if within a function

Tags: r

I have a function sourcing a script in its parent environment. The following works as expected:

```
cat("aa <- 77", file="script.R")
runScript <- function() source("script.R", local=parent.frame())

env <- new.env()
evalq(runScript(), envir=env)
ls.str(envir=env) # as expected: aa in env, not in globalEnv
rm(env)
```

When I wrap this in a function, the environment seems to be ignored:

```
thisfails <- function(expr){
  env <- new.env()
  evalq(expr, envir=env)
  ls(envir=env)
}

thisfails(runScript()) # why is aa in globalEnv?
rm(aa)
```

Now I would understand this with `eval`, but not with `evalq`, as the manual says: *eval evaluates its first argument in the current scope before passing it to the evaluator: evalq avoids this.*

Interstingly enough, this works:

```
works <- function(){
  runScript()
  ls()
}
works() # as expected: returns aa, doesn't create it in globalEnv
```

How can I use runScript as an expression inside a function and avoid it to be evaluated in globalEnv?

Comment: Incidentally, this question (and the fact that my initial answer was unsatisfactory) led me to [a new understanding of the semantics of `substitute`](https://twitter.com/klmr/status/1448628477880590336). “Yay.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fails because your function `thisfails` *itself* is using standard evaluation: `expr` is evaluated *before* being passed to `evalq`.

Instead, you need to capture the unevaluated argument via `substitute`, and pass the resulting expression to `eval`:

```
this_works <- function (expr) {
  env <- new.env()
  eval(substitute(expr), envir = env)
  ls(envir = env)
}
```

The confusing thing is that this looks exactly like the implementation of `evalq`! — after all, `evalq(expr)` is implemented as:

```
.Internal(eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos))
```

However, it is more accurate to think of `evalq(expr)` as being equivalent to `eval(quote(expr))`. That is, `expr` is understood *verbatim*, and is never evaluated. The actual implementation of `evalq` looks different simply because it needs to first retrieve the unevaluated expression represented by its `expr` argument in the calling scope, and that’s exactly what `substitute` does when called on an argument.

… Confusingly, `substitute` does something *different* for names in the global environment; namely, it leaves them untouched:

```
x = 1
substitute(x + 2)
# x + 2

in_function = function () {
    x = 1
    substitute(x + 2)
}

in_function()
# 1 + 2

in_env = new.env()
in_env$x = 1
substitute(x + 2, in_env)
# 1 + 2
```

Comment: Wow, this is crazy stuff! 
The last example should be substitute (*x* + 2, in_env)